# Getting "405 Not Allowed" after doing an Ajax post request for same domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would expect this to happen for CORS but I'm literally attempting something in the same domain and I'm at a loss.

I simple html form:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form contact-form">
            <div class="contact-input-fields">
              <p>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
                  <label for="name">Name*</label>
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control" required="">
                </span>
              </p>
              <p>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
                  <label for="email">Email*</label>
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control" required="">
                </span>
              </p>
              <p>
                <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
                  <label for="subject">Subject*</label>
                  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control" required="">
                </span>
              </p>
            </div><!-- /.contact-input-fields -->

            <p>
              <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">
                <label for="message">Message*</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" class="wpcf7-form-control" required=""></textarea>
              </span>
            </p>

            <p class="choose-table-form"> 
              <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" style="max-width:100%;"> 
            </p>
          </form><!-- /.contact-form -->
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".success").hide();
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var data = {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                subject: $("#subject").val(),
                message: $("#message").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "forms/contactForm.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    $(".success").fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $msg = "Name: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\Subject: ".$subject."\nMessage: ".$message;

//send email
    mail("email@domain.com", "Message" .$email, $msg);
}
```

I don't see anything wrong but everytime I press "submit" and trigger the ajax call I get the "405 Not Allowed".

I've looked around at other answers here but they're mostly CORS related.

Comment: Try using the full url to your ajax url `forms/contactForm.php`

Comment: Didn't work :( still get the 405

Comment: 405 is **method** not allowed. Does this work as a post without ajax?

Comment: A vanilla form you mean? I have other forms on the same server that work like that yes.

Comment: if you change method in your form to `get`, your ajax type to `GET` and change `$_POST` to `$_GET` in php, what happens?

Comment: @user6673915 - Do the other forms use `GET` or `POST` ?

Comment: @DavidDomain yes they use POST.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Get works...does that mean that POST is blocked? Except I didn't get the email, it just sent.

Comment: Looks like you are sending the form twice, you are not preventing the default behavior of the input submit button.

Comment: @DavidDomain I added it after the click (like Halnex shows on his example) still getting the 405.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any div with `success` class on it, so you need to add that to your HTML, I used bootstrap so it uses `alert-success`

```
<div class="alert-success">Done!</div>
```

And in your jQuery code, use `preventDefault();` and the full url to the php file

```
$(".alert-success").hide();
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            subject: $("#subject").val(),
            message: $("#message").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/jquery/forms/contactForm.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                $(".alert-success").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Also, make sure you are testing this within a server, whether localhost using wamp or xampp or on a live server.

Comment: If I include the entire url I get a CORS error is that expected in the same domain?

Comment: I have tested the code locally on my machine and I do not get any errors. Are you testing this inside localhost?